# Camera not turning on with Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: raspicam

My Raspberry Pi Camera is turned ON when connected to the Display port (Red LED is turned ON) but when connected to the Camera port it is not turned on (Red LED is OFF). The camera is also not detected. I have enabled the Camera option.

Answer (score 5):

If connected correctly, the camera LED does not turn on immediately.

Please make sure:

- To connect the camera to the right slot near the LAN port (with soldering side of the flat cable pointing away from the LAN port).
- To turn on camera support using `raspi-config`.

Now take some photos using `raspistill` on the command line.
**NOTE:** The camera LED turns on while capturing only!

Comment: There is a brief tutorial on the [blog of the official site](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/camera-board-available-for-sale/). With more detailed information in the [documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/raspbian/applications/camera.md). RTFM!